# Can't locate Email/Sender/simple.pm

Tags: perl, email

I want to send an email using perl `Email` module. I have installed `Email::Sender`. After running the following

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Email::Sender
```

and it says `Email::Sender is up to date`.

But when I run my script I get the following error:

> Can't locate Email/Sender/simple.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at ./first.pl line 8.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./first.pl line 8.

Script:

```
use Email::Sender::simple qw(sendmail); #line 8
use Email::Simple; #line 9
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The module is called `Email::Sender::Simple` (with two capital `S` characters), not `Email::Sender::simple`

Answer (score 0):

Although in perl-CPANEL shows the library installed correctly, it doesn't work, you can try next:

1) install epel repository from rpm (you can find it easy, by searching on google)

2) issue yum repolist

3) issue yum install perl-Mail-Sender.noarch